# Wordpress, How can i change ← Previous Entries to page numbers

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm wondering how I can change the "← Previous Entries" to like a page count, for example 1,2,3,4,5 and so on.

How can I do this with only PHP code, I can't really find anything on Google off course. Maybe I always search for the wrong name, but I've tried for like 30 minutes and this is my last shot!

You can see my Wordpress page here, this is a self designed website. http://codingdaily.net/freebies

Comment: What you are looking for is called pagination. If you google this word + wordpress should find what you are looking. [sample link](http://design.sparklette.net/teaches/how-to-add-wordpress-pagination-without-a-plugin/) [Second link](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress-pagination-a-primer/)

Comment: Again, I always search for the wrong words. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're referring to is called pagination.

[Wordpress Codex Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links)
[WPtuts Tutorial on pagination](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress-pagination-a-primer/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It depends from theme to theme.
You can customize using the next_posts_link and the previous_posts_link functions.

In the major of themes, you can check inside wp-content folder, themes, look for your theme then look for a file called loop.php.

Make a search for those functions above and you will see how it works.

Comment: This is a self designed wordpress blog. So I don't think i have that.